# how to append a implicit params use scala meta annotation?

Tags: scala, scalameta

for a example,append a implicit param id for `func` method:
**Before**

```
def func(p1: String) = { println("hi")}
```

**After**

```
@Param
def func(p1: String)(implicit id: String = "default") = { println("hi")}
```

Is scala meta able do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got how to do this:

```
//create Param  
val impParam = Term.Param(Nil, Term.Name("id"), Some(Type.Name("String")), Some(Term.Name("default")))
//append to existing params seq.`defn` is this method meta object
val appendImpParam = defn.paramss :+ impParam
```

Notice: you'd better check if the method had exist implicit params.